Finding the maximum of an integral
I am wondering if it is possible to find the maximum ($x_{\text{max}}$, $v_{\text{max}}$), also an approximate one, of this integral as function of $x$: $$v(x)=\int_0^{x+x_0} \frac{\exp \left[-\frac{(x-\tau )^2}{2}\right]}{\sqrt{\tau }} \, d\tau$$
Integrate[
 1/Sqrt[\[Tau]] Exp[-((x - \[Tau])^2/2)], {\[Tau], 0, x + x0}]

where $x_0>0$ and $x > -x_0$. For example, for $x_0=4$, we have varying $x$:
ListPlot[Table[{x, 
   NIntegrate[
    1/Sqrt[\[Tau]] Exp[-((x - \[Tau])^2/2)], {\[Tau], 0, x + x0} /. 
     x0 -> 4]}, {x, -4, 15, 0.1}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "v(x)"}]


From one side, I tried to find where $dv(x)/dx=0$, using the Leibniz integral rule, for which $$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{e^{-\frac{x_0^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{x+x_0}}+\int_0^{x+x_0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x-\tau )^2} (\tau -x)}{\sqrt{\tau }} \, d\tau$$
1/(E^(x0^2/2)*Sqrt[x + x0]) + 
 Integrate[(\[Tau] - x)/(E^((1/2)*(x - \[Tau])^2)*
     Sqrt[\[Tau]]), {\[Tau], 0, x + x0}]

but is seems that things get more complicated. On the other side, having checked that the maximum is near $t=0$, I tried to sobstitute to the integrand in $v(x)$ its Taylor expansion around $t=0$. In this case, the integral can be performed but the result is again much complicated depending on the number of terms kept from Taylor expansion.
If $x_0\rightarrow \infty$, the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ of the Taylor expansion of $$ \frac{\exp \left[-\frac{(x-\tau )^2}{2}\right]}{\sqrt{\tau }}$$ around $x=0$ truncated to the third order term is
$$v(x)\approx -\frac{1}{6} \left(x^2-4\right) \left(2^{3/4} x \, \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)+3 \sqrt[4]{2} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\right)$$ The last function has a maximum of $v_\text{maxapprox}=2.52714$ at $x_\text{maxapprx}=0.651579$ with $$x_\text{maxapprox}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2+\frac{8}{3} \sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^2}}{2^{3/4}}-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}$$ (Numerically, for $x_0 \rightarrow \infty$, the result should be $x_\text{max}=0.7649$ and $v_\text{max}=2.5596$.)
Any help or suggestion, also about the $x_0 \rightarrow \infty$ case, is really welcome.

I don't understand this question, since the integrand is positive for all $\tau$ the integral is maximal if x+x0 is maximal so for $x=\infty$

... or more precisely, the maximum does not exist.

I tried to explain what I am lookin for. Hopefully, it helps. Thank you for your comments.

If $x<0$, it would be $$v(x)=\sqrt{-\frac{x}{2}},e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}},K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici, thanks, this solution is very importat to me!

I have updated my first answer with the explicit formula for the $b_n$. By the way, if you consider that I provided an answer, may be, you could accept it in order other members of our community know it. Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici, thank you. Excuse me for the delay, I was trying to understand your answer. Do you use some Mathematica function to get help in finding the coefficients of the series? I am quite new about series expansion, probably it's time to face it.

@umby. Pattern recognition + a bit of heuristics+Mathematice to confirm and finish.

Using the same approach
Expanded around $x=0$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau }}\,\exp \Big[-\frac 12 (x-\tau )^2\Big]
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,\,e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n!}\,x^n$$
So,as you did, integrating with respect to $\tau$ from $0$ to $\infty$ to face
$$v(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\, x^n$$  where
$$b_n=\frac {2^{\frac{2n-3}{4} } } {n! }\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{2n+1}{4} \right)\,\,\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi 
   n}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi 
   n}{2}\right)\right)$$
is completely defined (as well as its derivatives.
This would be a fast convergent series since
$$\left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right|\sim \frac 1{\sqrt n} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Now, looking for the zero of $$v'_{(p)}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^p n\, b_n\, x^{n-1}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p &   x_{p} \\
 5 &  0.7957738274686 \\
 6 &  0.7693337827539 \\
 7 &  0.7627696942087 \\
 8 &  0.7645974040264 \\
 9 &  0.7651034151271 \\
10 &  0.7649737593594 \\
20 &  0.7649508673876 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
You should notice that, in principle, we do not need to solve the equation since, using power series reversion, we know its formal expression.

I was no able to find the expression for $b_n$, could you please add it to your answer? Thank you. @Claude Leibovici.

According to Mathematica, if $x>0$
$$v(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau }}\,\exp \Big[-\frac 12 (x-\tau )^2\Big]$$
$$v(x)=\frac{\pi}{2} \,  e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} \,\sqrt{x}\,\,
   \left(I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+I_{\frac{1
   }{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$v'(x)=\frac{\pi}{8 \sqrt{x}}\,  e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}\, ( A x^2+B)$$ with
$$A=I_{-\frac{5}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+I_{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(
   \frac{x^2}{4}\right)-2
   I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)-2
   I_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+$$ $$I_{\frac{3}{4}}
  \left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+I_{\frac{5}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}
   \right)$$ and
$$B=2
   \left(I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+I_{\frac{1
   }{4}}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\right)$$
Let $x=2 \sqrt t$ to make things simpler  to get
$$t=0.146287457380086381265076535841$$ Therefore
$$v'(x)=0 \quad \implies \quad x=0.764950867389759566027391419413$$ and a maximum value of
$$2.559609835371771925530303505$$
Nothing is proposed by the $ISC$ for these numbers.
Edit
The solution for the equation in $t$ can be viewed as
$$2t=-\frac{I_{-\frac{1}{4}}(t)+I_{\frac{1}{4}}(t) }{I_{-\frac{5}{4}}(t)+I_{-\frac{3}{4}}(t)-2
   I_{-\frac{1}{4}}(t)-2
   I_{\frac{1}{4}}(t)+I_{\frac{3}{4}}(t)+I_{\frac{5}{4}}(t) }$$
